# Is there how to measure the distance between two points?

Tags: graphing-functions

The function $$ y = x^3 - x^2 + x $$

Is there how to measure the distance between two points? Not the shortest, but the real size of the line between these points.

Comment: what two points? $y=x^3 -x^2 + x$ is a collection of infinite points

Comment: what kind of points?

Comment: coordinates (x,y)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is.

If $f$ is a differentable function defined at $[a,b]$ and this integral exists and it is finite
$$\int_a^b\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}dx$$
then it is the length of the curve $y=f(x)$ between $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$.

Comment: so I must start learning Integral. thank you